# Installing iPhone app onto device from Xcode, no files installing with app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've just set up a new computer and now trying to install my app onto my device through xcode. I've installed the certificates, developer provisioning files, etc..

The app is being installed onto my device, but none of the .png files are being loaded. So my app has the UIButtons and UILabels but nothing else is showing up in my app. Even though the simulator is running the app perfectly.

This app was just installing fine on my old computer to my device, with all the files included. Same version of Xcode and I'm not aware of any changes to settings I made that would have caused this.

No issues or errors when building the app, everything looks good.

Xcode 4.2.1, iPhone 4S 5.0

Thank you

Comment: Are the .png showing up in the project navigator? Did you use "Add Files..." to get them into the project?

Comment: First i ask to u how to create the .png file? are u directly change the name of the file like "filename.png" and then copy and paste in project?

Comment: Make sure you had images for Retina Display too i.e @2x.png in your application.Since iPhone 4S supports Retina dispaly.And add these files to your resource folder.

Comment: cool as long as it's solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's sometimes strange things like that which cache themselves in the `DerivedData` or `BuildIntermediates` folders of your Xcode project so rebuilding doesn't actually get any changes through. You may want to try `Product > Clean` and then build again, and then if nothing changes jump into the Xcode Organizer (`Window > Organizer`) and delete the Derived Data from the project. This will force a reindex of all the project files and any trace of prior builds will be deleted. It should then pick up all of the images as listed in your `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase(s).

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Cleaning the build didn't work, but deleting the Derived Data and then rebuilding/loading the project did the trick! Thanks!